# Best way to send notifications to an Android application

Tags: android, mobile, windows-mobile

I have a mobile application installed, say mail
I have a web service/web application being hosted for intimating the mobile app whenever he gets a mail.
Assume internet connection is ON in mobile.
I just want to know if the mobile app would be monitoring the server web service frequently for the mail or the server web service would take care and send/trigger the pop up to mobile once gets the mail (without the need for mobile to monitor).
Please assist and guide me to resolve this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would look into Android Cloud to Device Messaging.

Your application will receive an intent when a message arrives.

Link: http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/

Comment: Thanks for ur assistance. This C2DM service will intimate the Android devices only through internet. Correct?

Comment: @user the data is delivered over an IP connection.  It is not sent via SMS, if that is what you mean.

Comment: yes, so we need to host the service(A) in C2DM to send notifications.is it?basically our service(A) sends notifications.

Comment: how the service(A) hosted in C2DM will track the device and send the notification, is it based on the request been sent by mobile to this service? can u please clarify?

Comment: @user149535 I am not familiar with how they have implemented the service.  Let me look around the Google code page and see what I find.

Comment: Thanks for ur effort. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is the maximum capacity of c2dm broadcasts? how many broadcasts that a application server sends per mobile

Comment: in Google docs, they mentioned that 200000 messages per sender per day. is it 200000 broadcasts per sender/application server per day?

Answer (score 1):

In the specific case of mail, nearly every mail client is designed to poll (monitor) the remote server for mail.

In a more general sense, it depends what the app does. If there is an established protocol, it will dictate the mechanism for communication. If there is no guiding protocol, you need to disclose more about the situation for us to give advice on.

Comment: Thanks, kind of "facebook notifications to mobile devices". Please assist

Comment: How many users will you have for your app and how many notifications will you be sending per user?

Comment: users may be around 10000,notifications broadcasts per day may exceed 1000 per user

Answer (score 1):

According to this
http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/

Android cloud to device is official deprecated , Try Google cloud Messegin (GCM)
http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html